# What are the "options" using in unix shell?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I write the following shell script and cannot understand how it works.

```
#!/bin/bash
[ -n $HOME ]
echo $?
[ -z $HOME]
echo $?
```

Output = 0
                1

What is the use of -n and -z options

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions

Comment: `[ -z $HOME]` is a syntax error. Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: I found this book very helpful https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2085042.Sams_Teach_Yourself_Shell_Programming_in_24_Hours to understand  shell programming. You can check it.

Comment: You really need to double-quote variable references and use correct spacing, like `[ -z "$HOME" ]` instead of `[ -z $HOME]`

Comment: [bash(1) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) and click on the [CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#CONDITIONAL_EXPRESSIONS) link. (for all Linux questions, searching `"man7 nameoftool"` is a good place to start)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `-n` and `-z` you can check the length of a variable.

```
if [ -n "$HOME" ]; then
   echo "length of \$HOME ist not zero"
fi

if [ -z "$HOME" ]; then
   echo "length of \$HOME is zero"
fi
```